# How does setTimeout achieve throttling in this MDN example?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, throttling

In the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) documentation for the Element scroll event, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event), the following text is used to introduce the examples:

> The following examples show how to use the scroll event with an event listener and with the onscroll event handler property. The setTimeout() method is used to throttle the event handler because scroll events can fire at a high rate.

Then there are two sections of code where setTimeout is used, for our purposes they are the same (one uses the scroll event and the other uses the onscroll event):

```
element.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  output.innerHTML = "Scroll event fired!";
  setTimeout(() => {
    output.innerHTML = "Waiting on scroll events...";
  }, 1000);
});
```

How does this use of setTimeout achieve **throttling**? (The text states that it does.)

As I read it, it looks to me like there is no reduction in the number or frequency of calls to the function reference passed to setTimeout, there is just a delay (as clearTimeout is never called), and therefore throttling has not been achieved, the whole sequence has just been moved one second later.

Do subsequent calls to setTimeout replace previously scheduled function calls if they have not been executed? That would explain it, but I did not find any mention of that in the [MDN documentation for setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

Comment: It looks broken to me.

Comment: Yeah, I think the term throttling here is miss-leading, I think the `setTimeout` is there so you at least get to see the `output.innerHTML` otherwise the text would constantly say `Waiting on scroll events....`

Comment: Yes, that's not throttling. IIRC there used to be a real example of throttling back then, using rAF (which was actually useless too, since scroll fires in update the rendering too, but I digress). They may have updated the code example and kept that wording. And so for the code here, you'll get a nice burst of setTimeout handler firing at the same rate as the scroll event, all doing the same thing over and over.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some misunderstanding.
It seems that the example code shows when the scroll event occurs rather than the specific code that realizes throttling.

The text "Scroll event fired!" on the screen is displayed on the screen only when the scroll event is triggered.
Otherwise, it shows the text "Waiting on scroll events...".

Please note that this article is a commentary on "setTimeout() global function".

---

I will present the code that realized throttling.

```
var bEnabled = true;

element.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
 if (!bEnabled) return;

  bEnabled = false;
  setTimeout(() => enableCall = true, 300);

  output.innerHTML = "Scroll event fired!";
  setTimeout(() => {
    bEnabled = true;
    output.innerHTML = "Waiting on scroll events...";
  }, 1000);
});
```

In this way, after the callback is called once, all calls for 1 second are ignored.

Comment: What is the first setTimeout for? It doesn’t seem to do anything.